# how to hide html in Angular when object is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and I want to hide some specific HTMl in case of an Object is empty, but how can I achieve that?

so far I have:

```
$scope.links = data.links;
```

and then:

```
<div ng-if="links">
    /// some more html
</div>
```

but that doesnt work. Any help is appreciated...

Comment: What do you mean by *empty*? What type of object is `data.links`?

Comment: ng-if= 'links != []'

Comment: @upendrasinghsengar That's not a valid test

Comment: @RGraham sometimes, `console.log($scope.links)` returns `Object {}`

Comment: try this one ng-if= '{{links != []}}'

Comment: Why are you using `ng-if` and not `ng-show`/`ng-hide`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller:

```
$scope.linksLength = Object.keys(data.links).length > 0;
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-show="linksLength">
    /// some more html
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this I would write a simple function to use:

```
$scope.showLinks = function () {

  return $scope.links !== undefined && $scope.links !== null && $scope.links.length > 0;
}
```

then

```
<div ng-if="showLinks()">
    /// some more html
</div>
```

Comment: Assuming `links` is indeed an array, `ng-if="links.length"` would be fine as the view code chomps exceptions if the expression is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.length` to `ng-if="links"` then change `ng-if` to `ng-show`.

**E.g.**

```
<div ng-show="links.length">
    /// some more html
</div>
```

If `ng-show` detects that the value of `links.length` is 0 then it's `false` if not equal to 0 then it's `true`.

`0` = `false`

`> 0` = `true`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

use ngHide or ngShow.

```
<div ng-show="links.length">
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" >
<p ng-hide="isempty(products)">element</p>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.products=[];

$scope.isempty=function(obj)
{
return (angular.equals([], obj));
}
});
</script>
</body>
```